# How to use email OTP instead of authenticator TOTP in identityserver4+AspNetCode.Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am posting this in order someone else has the same problem, because I couldn't find any online documentation.

The problem:

Using https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin (IdentityServer4, using Microsoft.AspnetCore.Identity for authentication), how to change the default Authenticator TOTP and use email-based OTP instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the following line in AccountController:

   return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberLogin });
2. **Add** before:

   var code = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email");

   _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "TwoFactor code", htmlEmail);
3. Find line:

   var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, model.RememberMe, model.RememberMachine);
4. **Replace** it with:

   var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email", authenticatorCode, model.RememberMe, model.RememberMachine);

I hope it saves someone some trouble.

Comment: it has been awhile but thanks for the post. Any idea how I could change the default expiry time for this password?